# First 9 members from a prestigious list

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

Upon completion, these are the first 9 members from a prestigious list to form the name of their field.

1. Carl Bosch
2. Hermann Emil Fischer
3. Eduard Buchner
4. Marie Sklodowska Curie
5. Irving Langmuir
6. Svante Arrhenius
7. Theodore William Richards
8. Richard Willstatter
9. 

---

***Who is the missing member?***

Comment: Thank you for the puzzle! Some feedback from me: rot13(Tvivat gur shyy anzrf znqr vg dhvgr rnfl gb fcbg gur pbaprvg. V guvax gur chmmyr jbhyq unir orra zber bs n punyyratr vs lbh whfg tnir gur ynfg anzrf. )

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will make similar puzzles challenging from next time. I should have taken more time in framing this one. I posted it too quickly when the idea for this puzzle came across to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing member is

> [Yuan Tseh Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan_T._Lee)

> All people are winners of the [Nobel Prize in Chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates_in_Chemistry) and the first letters of their first names spell **CHEMISTRY**.
>  As [stewartIM pointed out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118203/first-9-members-from-a-prestigious-list#comment330445_118205), these people are the first laureates who have that specific initial, which makes this fit the "first 9 members" clue.

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: Don't forget that rot13(rnpu vf gur rneyvrfg zrzore puebabybtvpnyyl jvgu gung vavgvny)